# click event calling an unreferenced function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the purposes of this post, please see my JSFiddle located at http://jsfiddle.net/ca7ws/

This is my menu. Clicking one of the last 3 (Scoring / Historical / Administrative) bring up a sub menu. Clicking a link on the sub menu *should* add the "selectedMenu" class. It appears as though it does not.

By adding alert("someText") to each function, I noticed that when

```
JQuery(".menuLinksSub li").click(function(){
```

is called,

```
jQuery(".menuCategory").click(function(){
```

is also called.

So the class is added and then immediately taken away, giving the appearance of not having worked at all.

My initial thought was that it was inherent in the NAV and UL behavior, so I even went so far as to remove all NAV / UL / LI tags in my HTML and replace them with DIV / SPAN but to no avail. The behavior is the same.

I've tried quite a bit and am stumped. Any help you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shadraq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is bubbling upwards through the DOM, as most events do. You have to stop it from the inner event handler:

```
jQuery(".menuLinksSub li").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ... your logic
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ca7ws/1/

Comment: prefect. That works great. Thanks for the quick and accurate help. For my information moving forward, is there some documentation as to what you did there? I'd like to read up on it a bit so I don't make this mistake again.

Comment: @theShadraq to explain this simply, when you click a `.menuLinksSub li` element, you're also clicking on the `.menuCategory` div containing it (technically, right? it makes sense when you think about it). 

the click event is handled starting with the innermost element and working out. so you have to tell the click event to stop propagating upwards once you've handled it for the innermost element. (this is a fantastic reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: @theShadraq See [the jQuery docs on this method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). I also like [the old quirksmode page on events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html), it's old but most of the info there still applies.

Comment: @sgroves thanks for the quick explanation. that helped quite a bit

Comment: @bfavaretto - Thanks for the links and the answer. a great help to me. I appreciate it

Comment: As an alternative, you can also return false from your click function to disable further propagation

Comment: @Lochemage Yes, but note that `return false` will also prevent the default behavior. It doesn't make any different in a li, but if it were a link, it would not be followed.